# Access returned data from database using PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am trying to access from two columns,  one from Count(userid) and another from rank.  This code do return for the count but not for the
rank.

```
<?php

$myusername = strtolower($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = md5($_POST['password']);
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(userid), rank FROM users_ WHERE "
        . "username = ? AND password = ?";   // note the "?" placeholders
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$myusername, $mypassword]);

$row = $stmt->fetch();
//echo $row[0]; // this displays the returned count.
echo $row[1];
if ($row[0] == 1) {
    header("location: dashboard.php");
} else {
    $error = "Invalid username or password.";
}
```

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: there is no rank column in your query

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be rank not username.  Edited it.

Comment: Your retrieving `COUNT(userid)` and also rank?  You probably should remove the COUNT() and just check if a userid is found.

Comment: userid is found along with rank if COUNT() is removed.  It would be better if I could find COUNT() along with rank.